# How do i show the difference between dates where one is getting the current date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-9

So for my to-do list, im trying to show in my view the difference in number of days between the current date and the date that the task is suppose to be completed by. But i cant seem to do that because im using date_diff() function and it only accepts objects and not strings for the data types.

This is the error message

```
date_diff(): Argument #1 ($baseObject) must be of type DateTimeInterface, string given
```

This is my controller

```
public function saveItem(Request $request) {

        $newTask = new task;

        if ($request->task == null) {
            abort(404);
        }

            $newTask->tasks = $request->task; 
            $newTask->is_complete = 0;
            $newTask->task_date = date("Y-m-d");
            
            if($request->day === "tomorrow") {

                $date = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
                date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
                $newTask->date_of_completion = date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
                
            } elseif($request->day === "today") {

                $newTask->date_of_completion = date("Y-m-d");
            }
            
            $newTask->save();
            return redirect('/');

    }
```

This is my view

```
<p class="flex items-center px-4 py-1 rounded-lg text-[#555]">{{ date_diff(date("Y-m-d"), date_create($task->date_of_completion)) }}</p>
```

If i can find out how to change or use something else to get the current date as an object so that it can be used in my date_diff(), it will really help but if you have a better solution that is much easier, im open it to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date_diff need DateTimeInterface type for the first parameters, in your code, you send it a string. date("Y-m-d") will return current date with format Y-m-d.

To solve it, you just need to change your code into:

```
date_diff(new \DateTime, date_create($task->date_of_completion))
```

Maybe for easier to use, you can take a look for [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-introduction)

Comment: i just tried using the first method but it didnt work and got this error 

 ( htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, DateInterval given )

im gonna try and use carbon and see if it works

Comment: When you use date_diff method, you cant print it as date_diff result, because its an object. You have to choose which date diff you will print, i.e date_diff result stored in variable $diff, so if you want to get diff by day, you can print it by $diff->format("%d days");. For more format type, you can read on this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow this link and solve your error.

https://www.coderrize.com/how-do-i-show-the-difference-between-dates-where-one-is-getting-the-current-date-in-laravel/19

Thank you!

Comment: Let's expand on that link-only answer by adding some of your own first-hand insights.

Answer (score 0):

Add `date_of_completion` field to `$casts` property, so it can be cast to a Carbon instance (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).

Then, simply call `$task->date_of_completion->diffForHumans()` and it calculates that for you (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff).